# How to get value of "listen" in Nginx?

Tags: nginx

Have code in Nginx:

```
    server_name site.ru www.site.ru;
    listen 111.10.111.0;
    charset CP1251;
    disable_symlinks if_not_owner from=$root_path;
    include file.conf;
```

How me to get value of "listen" (value - 111.10.111.0) from file.conf? Is there a variable for this? Thank you.

Comment: This reads like an x/y problem - _why_ do you want to know the listen directive value in an included file? @Julqas this is not a php question.

Comment: @AD7six You're right I assumed it was a question associated with some programmation server-side because of the word "variable". First thoughts were for PHP, don't really know why haha.